# Exception Handling Decorator violating LSP

Tags: dependency-injection, decorator, liskov-substitution-principle

I am currently reading Mark Seeman's and Steven van Deursen's book "Dependency Injection" (Second Edition, but same example is in first edition).

In chapter 9.2.2 "Reporting exceptions using the Decorator pattern" he proposes an exception handling decorator that decorates an abstraction with catching certain exceptions and opening an alert box instead of bubbling up the exception to the consumer.

He states that adheres to the SRP and OCP, which I can follow.

In my opinion, however, that violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The exceptions thrown by an abstraction belong to the contract. If they are caught and transformed to an alert message in a decorator, the consumer does not explicitly know that. The consumer either has to implicitly know that a decorator was applied to care for handling the exceptions, which would be odd in my opinion, or he does not know that, in which case he has to care for exception handling himself to adhere to the contract and the LSP, which would make the decorator useless.

In my opinion the consumer must not know that an abstraction was decorated, he should adhere to the contract the abstraction provides.

My proposal would be a new interface `IExceptionHandlingAbstraction` that is implemented by an adapter that catches the exceptions of `IAbstraction` and transforms it to alert boxes. That way the consumer can rely on the contract of `IExceptionHandlingAbstraction` and explicitly knows he need not handle exceptions himself.

Because I have a really great trust in Mark's posts, answers and books I am not quite sure if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the consumer must not know that an abstraction was decorated, he should adhere to the contract the abstraction provides.

That is correct. In order to adhere to the LSP, both implementations of the abstraction should adhere to the same contract. But the question now becomes: what exactly is the contract? What can the consumer expect.

In contrast with Java, .NET does not force exceptions as part of the method definition. And I think this is fine. You can't, and shouldn't constraint the exceptions thrown to an abstraction. This of course changes when you throw exceptions that the client is expected to handle. In that case, the exception type should be part of the contract.

A bigger problem in that particular decorator example, IMO, is that the exception doesn't bubble up. It is completely swallowed. This can certainly be considered a violation of the (implicit) contract, as a developer would expect the call to have succeeded when no exception is thrown. So I do agree that the example is a bit naive and does violate LSP.

That example, however, is not meant to be a full-proof, 100% SOLID solution, but rather as an example to demonstrate the power of Interception using Decorators. And also note that in chapter 10 we explain that being 100% SOLID is neither possible nor desirable. It's all about tradeoffs and perhaps this decorator example works well in the particular client application you are building, although I do expect a consumer (a form) to need to know whether the operation succeeded, because you typically want to close the form when it completed. But in that case, I expect a design as stipulated in chapter 10 to be a better solution.

> My proposal would be a new interface `IExceptionHandlingAbstraction` that is implemented by an adapter that catches the exceptions of `IAbstraction` and transforms it to alert boxes

Creating a new abstraction that allows the consumer to get notified or informed about failures is a good solution around the LSP violation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the changed "return behavior" is the actual violation. In my `IExceptionHandlingAbstraction` I used a bool as return value to indicate success.

Comment: Returning a bool might be a bit tricky, because that's an error code, and consumers tend to forget to check error codes. Instead, a solution I used in the past is to pass in a continuation (delegate) that will be called either on success or on failure (depending on what's most useful, but I used on success).

Comment: Yes sure, that's a more functional approach, I also tend to use it more and more often to get safety.